# Need Orchestration and BPEL looks good, but can you completely avoid webservices?

Tags: web-services, soap, bpel, orchestration, apache-ode

I need orchestration and Apache ODE looks good. However, we need to avoid webservices (soap ) completely. We don't want to deal with that technology as as all our services are "rest" based. Is this possible if we use Apache ODE?

A BPEL workflow becomes a webservice. Is it possible to make it Rest-based service?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use WSDL 1.1 extensions for REST as discussed in the Apache ODE documentation

http://ode.apache.org/extensions/wsdl-11-extensions-for-rest.html